# Why is my mesh black when rendering?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I added a mesh and made into a ceiling, in Blender. I applied some color to it, but when I render, the mesh is just black; the other objects are fine and have color. How do I fix this? I tried deleting it and inserting it again or copy-pasting the other objects but it still turns black.

[image]

[image: The ceiling is black :(]

Comment: Are you sure that the material you used was created in the BI engine?

Comment: did you check the meshes normals?

Comment: to get a fast answer please edit your question showing how the material for that object is setup, or better still, upupload your .blend file.

Comment: try to rotate it 180° on X or Y axis to see if it's just inverted normals, else see cegaton's comment

Comment: @Bithur i tried inverting it but it's just the same.

Comment: @cegaton i already uploaded the .blend file sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have area lights (with a really small size?) upon your ceiling, pointing downward.
[image]
Your ceiling is in it's own shadow! I didn't use BI for a long time, so i don't even understand that you have your walls visible...
Anyway, add some point lights under the ceiling or some area with low energy pointing up.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you are using point lights, and the celling mesh is way too high up to get affected by them (quite possible if you are using the position of the 3D cursor to create it). To fix either move the celling down, or change its material to an unshaded one.

Another reason for this to happen might be that you are using a material with a black color.

That's all I can think of right now. If you post a .blend file that has the same issue, maybe you will get a better answer than mine...

Comment: i already uploaded the .blend file sir

Comment: @FrancisJessieS.EnriquezJr. sorry, didn't notice :D. (BTW, please don't call me sir, I'm a bit too young for that...)

Comment: Marinov i call u sir because ur gonna teach me sorry for calling u that way